# What does the [@[bar foo]] operator do in Excel, in particular the at sign?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've seen someone construct what seemed like cell references in Excel that looked like

```
=[@[column title]]*someothercell
```

What is this feature called, are the rectangular brackets and the at sign independent or do they belong together? How does it work precisely?

I've googled around for a while and tried by hand in Excel, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The square brackets are used for [structured references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e), which make it easier to reference data in named tables (which you can create by going to Insert → Table).

The `@` is [new notation in Excel 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20130727024317/http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/01/25/table-improvements-in-excel-2010.aspx) replacing `[#This Row]` from Excel 2007. The at symbol is used to shorten formulas inside named tables referencing cells in the same row.

The inner square brackets are only needed because your `bar foo` table heading contains a space.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!! Using your link at a starting point, I was able to figure out the rest - hope it is okay I edited it into your answer to be able to give you the green checkmark :-).

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg No problem, thanks for contributing!

Comment: @Indrek I'm working with Excel 2013 and omitting the `@` seems to still work - do you know what exactly is the difference between `[@somecol]` and `[somecol]`?

Comment: Very old thread but in case it's useful... The @symbol is used to select the current row, omitting this will select all rows in that column. This is only apparent when using aggregate such as sum, average etc. so `=AVERAGE([@MyDataColumn])` would just the return the same value present in MyDataColumn but `=AVERAGE([MyDataColumn])` would return the average of the entire column